# Codeigniter command line: The configuration file does not exist

Tags: php, command-line, codeigniter-3

I have a Codeigniter 3.1.7 project locally and the same on my server for environnement testing.

In local I can launch commands via:

```
php index.php manage save_existing_documents
```

and it works!
But on testing, codeigniter work fine, 
except with the command line^^
He shows me:

```
The configuration file does not exist
```

Yet the config.php file is in application/config/testing/config.php^^

The folder testing is a symlinks and it works for the rest of the project

Thank for your help!

Comment: and how do you load that config file?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, in index.php:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

Set to environment while in testing, codeigniter looks for its conf in the development folder^^

Comment: delete this answer and edit the original question to add the extra data